# Difficulty importing .dat file

Tags: python, pandas

I am somehow having difficulty reading in this file into python with pandas read_table function. 
http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/econometrics/invest.dat

This is my code:

```
pd.read_table(f,skiprows=[0], sep="")
```

Which yields error:

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Dont know about read_table, but you can read this file directly as follows:

```
import pandas as pd    

with open('/tmp/invest.dat','r') as f:
    next(f) # skip first row
    df = pd.DataFrame(l.rstrip().split() for l in f)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
              0            1             2            3
0     17.749000   0.66007000    0.15122000   0.33150000
1     3.9480000   0.52889000    0.11523000   0.56233000
2     14.810000    3.7480300    0.57099000   0.12111000
...
...
```

The same can be obtained as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/invest.dat', sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Just thought it might be more efficient to do so with built-in functions. Do you know of anyway to do it with built-in functions?

Comment: you can simply use ``skiprows=0``

Comment: Thanks a ton. I think the trick is to use regular expression in the sep argument. Cause when I use "\s+", even with read_table, it works.

Comment: Good to hear its ok now:-)

Comment: Thank you also for the `\s+`. The number of space being inconsistent during the import you can't use a simple `' '` space.