# What is the python equivalent to @@ in SAS?

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I am trying to import a .dat file into a pandas dataframe for analysis.

A row in the .dat file contains 2 observations (year, population, and crime) and looks like this:

```
1960  179323175  3384200  1961  182992000  3488000
```

[Marcin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413843/difficulty-importing-dat-file) was very helpful, however, I seem to have multiple observations on one row (as the .dat file is structured). Is there an equivalent to the @@ option in SAS, that allows pandas to specify the number of columns (or a better solution)? Thank you.

```
#importing .dat files into pandas
with open('Data_Exercises/CHAPTER4/DATA for Exercises 4.1 and 4.4.dat','r') as f:
    #next(f) # this is what you would write to skip the first row.skip first row
    df = pd.DataFrame((l.rstrip().split() for l in f))

print(df)
```

[image: This is a view of the printout. I am not allowed to embed images yet.]

Comment: You might want to explain what "the @@ option in SAS" does that you can't do in Python; I suspect many Python experts are not familiar with SAS syntax.

Comment: Thank you, mustaccio. The @@ option will allow for one row of data to contain multiple entries. It uses the inputs (i.e. column names) to know how many observations are included (e.g. if there are 3 inputs and 9 pieces of delimited data, then there are 3 observations).

Comment: Probably it's just me, but this explanation doesn't help much. Regardless, you should edit your question and add it there, not in the comments.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a way to produce a union of  columns 0-2 and 3-5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :3], df.iloc[:, 3:]], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach helped get me there! (I would upvote, but lack the minimum 15 reputation required).