# Import ".dat" file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a ".dat" file that looks like this:

[image]

You can download it here: 
https://filebin.net/hnhsv8sc3zvaoi8k

I would like to read this file into a pandas data frame. I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413843/difficulty-importing-dat-file) and tried the solution:

```
with open('Output2.dat','r') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(l.rstrip().split() for l in f)
```

The result looks like that:

[image]

- the row "Balance" was displaced, How to change that?
- How can I make sure that the first row is added as pandas column titles?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: 
This is how the final Table should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "empty elements" are `0xa0` bytes; non-breaking spaces in Latin-1, but spaces nevertheless, therefore they are seen as whitespace by `str.split`.

Here's a hacky workaround that works:

```
with open("Output2.dat", "rb") as f:  # binary mode
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [e.decode("latin-1") if e != b'\xa0' else None for e in l.strip().split()]
        for l in f
    )
```

Here I'm opening the file in binary mode, because `bytes.split` ignores that special space. When I detect it, I further replace it with `None` to not have some weird character in the empty cells.

I'm assuming a latin-1 encoding, because `0xa0` on its own is invalid UTF-8, but you may need to replace that with `windows-1252` or some other encoding, depending on where this data is coming from.

Comment: That's very nice ! Thanks a lot ! Is there a way to add the first row as column names in the pandas dataframe ?

Comment: Sure, you could do something like `columns = [element.decode("latin-1") for element in next(f).strip().split()]` before the line where you define the dataframe, and provide them as columns like `df = pd.DataFrame(([e.decode....] for l in f), columns=columns)`